# Convergence in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$.

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I do not know how to show that:

$1+p+p^{2}+\ldots$ converges to $\frac{1}{1-p}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ where $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is the set of $p$-adic numbers.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Convergence of series in $p$-adics is simple - a series converges if the terms converge to zero. Proving that depends on a how you have defined $p$-adic numbers. (There are several different ways to define $p$-adics, which all turn out to be equivalent.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggestion/hint: Write $s_n = 1+p +\cdots + p^n$. Then $ (1-p) s_n -1 = -p^{n+1} $. Divide throughout by $(1-p)$:
$$ s_n - {1\over 1- p} = {-p^{n + 1} \over 1- p }. $$ The absolute value of the RHS tends to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between them is a sum of very high powers of $p$.  In other words, it is very small in the $p$-adic metric.